# Как сохранить некоторую область как картинку во флеше?

Tags: flash

Доброго времени суток.
Есть небольшой проект на флеше. Что-то вроде редактора: есть рабочая область и кнопки с инструментами. После наполнения рабочей области ее надо сохранить как картинку. Как это сделать? Или с чего начать поиски?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Привет, предлагаю такой вариант:

- находим DisplayObject который нужно сохранить (mc_canvas)
- ставим кнопку
- на кнопку подписываем указанный ниже метод слушатель

  ```
  button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSavePictureButtonClicked);

  private function onSavePictureButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
      var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(mc_canvas.width, mc_canvas.height);
      bitmapData.draw(mc_canvas);  

      var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(quality_slider.value);
      var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

      byteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

      var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
      fileReference.save(byteArray, '.jpg');  
  }
  ```

Ссылки на похожий код:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638137/as3-air-mobile-save-bitmap-to-file
http://permadi.com/blog/2011/02/flash-as3-saving-image-to-disk/